# Closed form of convex optimization problem by using Least Squares Methods

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, convolution, least-squares, convex-optimization

I want to solve below optimization problem by using Least Squares methods.

[image]

where [image] is unknown convex function (e.g. [image])

and [image] is convolution operator

I want to know the closed form of above optimization problem by using Least Square Methods, but there is unknown convex function *F(x)*, which makes me hard to get closed form of it.

Comment: Well, if F is the norm-square (seems to be a likely use case), then maybe you can make progress via the identity FT(x*y) = FT(x) FT(y) where FT = Fourier transform, and applying Parseval's theorem somehow. It might also be relevant that the FT is a linear transformation. Just guessing at this point. Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: You won't find a closed form solution for any convex function. You may iterative solution for any function assuming the gradient is known.

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem is of the form:

[image]

Where $\boldsymbol{D}$ is the derivative operator, then the problem is basically a regularized deconvolution problem.

One of the best framework to solve such problem is the ADMM as seen in:

- [Solve Image Denoising with Total Variation Prior Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75231).
- [Solve an Image Deblurring Problem by Variational Methods Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75554).
- [Solve Non Blind Image Deblurring with Total Variation Prior Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75471).
- [Solving inverse problem using black box implementation of the kernel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87500).

In those answers you will find a MATLAB code to solve such problem.

In case your fidelity term is different, it is OK as long as you know how to calculate the gradient.